# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Optiplex 9020

Tags: 14.04, boot, uefi

After disable safe boot options on BIOS, change UEFI to Legacy option I could  boot Ubuntu from USB, it is not installed on computer. But it skips part of the left side of the screen and does not show the usual message for 'try ubuntu' or 'install ubuntu'. Tried ctrl+alt+t, but nothing happened. First tried Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and it was quite the same. Could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you intend to dual-boot with an already-installed Windows system, go back into your firmware and disable the BIOS/CSM/legacy option that you enabled. Such a configuration creates the opportunity for problems related to the boot mode. If you intend to single-boot Ubuntu, then the boot mode isn't so important. If you can't get the Ubuntu installer to boot except by enabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support, then chances are you either have a Secure Boot problem (in which case disabling that feature in your firmware may help) or you created your boot medium incorrectly (in which case you should examine the options you used to be sure the program creates an EFI-bootable medium or switch to another program). I cover all of this in more detail in [this Web page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

Second, your description of the problem is a little unclear; I'm not sure what you mean by "it skips part of the left side of the screen" -- are you saying the screen is partially blank? You also don't say what you *do* see, which is at least as important as what you *don't* see. Posting a screen shot (a digital photo is fine) would be helpful in diagnosing this problem.

Comment: Hey Rod! What I saw was the right part of the usual ubuntu desktop front view, but the unity bar on the left wasn't there at all. I did here some changes (can't precise what) and ubuntu started properly from the USB. I'm installing Ubuntu erasing Windows 8 that came in the machine. 

I'm in doubt if should back to UEFI and enable secure boot again  when installation ends. What you think?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: As Rod mentioned, changing a machine that has EFI/UEFI already on it can cause issues. You are wiping Windows 8 completely so there should be no issue. I would recommend changing your boot back to the way it is for future use.

Comment: The main point to not enabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support is to avoid mis-matches between two installed OSes. If you're completely removing Windows, such a mis-match is impossible, and so BIOS/CSM/legacy support is much less likely to cause problems. Once Ubuntu is installed and booting, changing a firmware option related to boot mode can cause problems and is almost certain to *not* solve problems -- but if you install and can't boot, there's a chance that changing this boot option will fix the problem. That's all highly hypothetical, though.